# When does dodge chance take effect?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Does the game roll for my dodge chance when the enemy weapon is fired, or when it would hit my ship?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Dodge chance takes effect differently depending on whether or not you have shields.

- If you have **no shields**, dodge is calculated when your ship is about to be hit.
- If you **do have shields**, dodge is calculated when they are about to be hit.

This may seem like a trivial distinction, but there is one important result of this: **Missiles**.  Even though missiles bypass shields, the dodge is still calculated as the missile passes the shield barrier.

So if you are using a Cloaking Device, use it before things hit your shield.

Comment: Does this also hold true for enemy ships? If I hit their engine bay (with other shots closely behind), does the evade chance get recalculated for each subsequent shot?

Answer (score 12):

It seems to be when the shots are about to hit your ship.
I use my cloak right after the enemy fires its volley which takes my evade to around 90%-105%, giving a hit free volley cycle for me every time.