# When is the Evade chance calculated for enemy ships?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When firing a multi-shot weapon in *FTL: Faster than Light*, such as the *Burst Laser Mk II*, Each shot has a separate chance to hit or miss it's target.

Say I'm firing at an Engine Bay on an Automated Scout with no shields. For the purposes of this example, lets say that the ship's current evade chance is 20%, and the Engine Bay is fully powered and has 2 hitpoints.

I fire my <strike>lazor</strike> *Burst Laser Mk II*, and the first shot hits the Engine, taking one hitpoint and dropping the Evade chance to 15%. Are the subsequent shots (that the weapon fired before the Evade chance dropped) calculated against the original 20% chance, or the new 15% chance? *When does the enemy ship's evade chance get calculated?*

Comment: I don't have any evidence of this, so it isn't an answer, but it seems from my play as if hit/miss calculations happen at the edge of the bubble defined by the shield, whether the shield is up or not.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102102/when-does-dodge-chance-take-effect